# Http <link type="prefetch" vs. pragma: no-cache

Tags: cross-browser, http-headers, httprequest, browser-cache, prefetch

What will happen if a html page has a prefetch link to a resource that has a no-cache pragma header?

Comment: What did you observe when you tested it? And why do you expect the two to affect each other?

Comment: Well I've only peeked at google chrome network pane and i see every prefetch request has been canceled.

Comment: The documentation says that prefetch (“prerendering”) is aborted when Developer Tools is open: https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender

Comment: So I can check if prerendering occurred, but not how?

Comment: You can check it e.g. by referring to a URL that causes a server-side side effect, just not with Developer Tools. But the question remains why you expect this to be affected by a pragma.

Comment: if i correctly understood the prefetch instructs the browser to cache the linked resource in its "spare time", and the pragma: no-cache instructs the browser to not cache something. I think that these two thins will interfere with each other at some point. The question is just a theroric question: will something happen, according to rfc or browser implementations, maybe by cancelling the prefetch request?

Maybe browser are dumb and download the linked resource but when loading a page that requires that resouce will download it again...

Comment: Prefetching means that the browser loads the resource. Whether it then caches it is a different issue.

Comment: but if it loads a resource without actually using it will it be discarded on subsequent request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but if it loads a resource without actually using it will it be discarded on subsequent request?

This is browser dependent. IE11 operates as follows:

> Prerendered pages are not always displayed to the user. These conditions cause prerendered pages to be discarded from memory without being displayed:

```
The user doesn't open the target page within five minutes.
The user opens a different page.
The user switches to a different tab or browser instance.
A JavaScript process adds a new link element that requests a different webpage to prerender.
An error occurs while loading the target page, including HTTP error code 500 (server error), 404 (resource not found), or related errors (such as connection problems).
```

> When a prerendered page is discarded and then requested later, it's loaded from the hosting server directly. If the page is still in browser cache, it might load more quickly; however, this is not guaranteed.

**References**

- [Prerender and prefetch support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn265039)

Answer (score 1):

All of the browsers (with prefetch support) will load the document in their idle time (with `Pragma: no-cache` or/and `Cache-Control: no-cache`) so we'd like to know whether they take it from cache or will they request it again when user actually "clicks" the link.

From the quick investigation I've done recently (*browsers are of latest versions*):

- **Chrome/Opera** loads from cache
- **Firefox** requests again
- **IE/Edge** requests again
- **Safari** doesn't support

So I'd suggest to set some cache period (e.g. 5-10 minutes) for the resource you want to prefetch if you want it to be taken from cache on browsers other than chromium based.